# How to remove jagged shadows in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have these jagged shadows on the edges of the spiral I have added a subdivision surface modifier with 3 subdivisions, and set smooth shading even then I'm getting these jagged shadows on the edges in cycles, How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: What happens if you increase the subdivision to 4 levels? Have you tried applying 1-2 levels of subdivision, then smoothing the mesh?

Comment: i changed increased the levels, It is decerasing the jaggedness but wouldn't it increase render time?

Comment: It will take longer to create the BVH, but you'll get smoother reflections. Render times shouldn't go up too much.